# Reading from file to add to list

Tags: python

I need to get from list(file) who is coming to party and who is not.

File looks like this:

```
(+) John
(?) Jake
(+) Billie
```

How to read that person with + is coming ?

Comment: Try reading the text and then splitting it(with the spaces), check every even index and if it is a plus, append the element at the next index to the list

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open("your_file", "r")
c = []
for line in file:
    if line[1] == '+':
        c.append(line[4:].strip())
print(c)
```